# Setup VS CODE tasks.json to use buildArgs for my docker build

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

My docker build has one build argument that uses the env variable by the same name and another defined explicitly:

```
docker build --build-arg ARGUMENT1 --build-arg ARGUMENT2=foo .
```

The VS CODE documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/reference#_dockerbuild-object-properties)
does not make it clear how to define the `buildArgs`.  It says

> Build arguments applied to the command line. This is a list of key-value pairs.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "docker-build",
      "type": "docker-build",
      "dockerBuild": {
        "buildArgs": {WHAT DO I PUT HERE?}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried

```json
{
   "buildArgs": {
       "ARGUMENT1":"$ARGUMENT1",
        "ARGUMENT2":"foo"
   }
}
```

which produced:

```
docker build --build-arg "ARGUMENT=$ARGUMENT" --build-arg "ARGUMENT2=foo"
```

I think this might be how to do it.  Not sure if there is a way to not have the extra double quotes for the `build-arg`